# how to convert current transformer coil ac voltage to dc voltage

Tags: current-transformer

i want to measure the current drawn by an AC application in 220v with a ct coil and will interface its generated signal (rectified dc voltage) to PLC.

need suggestion for this project.

thanks and regards

Comment: What sort of suggestions are you looking for. Seems to me your question sets out the method adequately so what's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use what is known as a precision rectifier circuit to remove the voltage drops that result from rectifier diodes. Here is a typical circuit configuration that will get you what you want:

[image]

This circuit comes [from this applications note](https://www.crmagnetics.com/Assets/ProductPDFs/Precision%20Rectifier%20Circuit%20for%20CT%20Signal%20Conditioning.pdf) published on the web.

Answer (score 0):

What is the nominal output current range from your CT?

How much accuracy do you need?

The standard inexpensive approach is to feed the output winding of the CT into a bridge rectifier and then to the burden resistor.  Because the output of the CT is a current, the output voltage rises to compensate for the voltage drop in the rectifier diodes.

Pick the value of the burden resistor to give you the appropriate voltage when the CT is being fed its maximum current.

You would then follow the bridge rectifier with whatever filtering you need.  The amount of filtering depends on several competing factors: how much ripple can you tolerate, how fast must the output be, what is the load impedance seen by the filter network.

However, this is not the most accurate approach.  The accuracy can be decent (a couple of percent) but it is not what I would consider to be "instrumentation grade".

If a few percent accuracy is acceptable, the above should work nicely for you.  If you do need instrumentation-grade accuracy, modify your question appropriately.

Comment: This is the low cost simple way to do it but it demands that the CT output rises by two forward voltage drops in the bridge. This rise in output voltage can cause the current transformer core to trend toward saturation. It is always best to minimize the voltage drop across the CT and burden resistor to in the millivolts range as opposed to the volts range.